# Block Internet for Apps without Disconnecting from WiFi in Android

Tags: android, wifi, disconnect

I'm trying to block Internet access in android without disconnecting from WiFi Network.

I need a trick except making dump VPN!

I'm trying to change wifi configurations but it's not working....

Is there any trick to block internet data without disconnecting from wifi?!

Answer (score 1):

You can use what's called "root" and modify the /etc/hosts file in order to block internet access...

Please note: To use superuser permissions the device must be rooted. Otherwise your app won't work.

Using a VPN is another good idea... Why don't you want to?